# Can I route GA events from default tracker to named tracker? (OR make Vimeo use my named tracker?)

Tags: google-analytics, vimeo

## Context

I'm using the [Vimeo analytics script](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224980588-Integrating-with-Google-Analytics) to integrate video events with Google Analytics. The page I'm working on needs to route all GA events to a named tracker as created by...

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto', { name: 'MyTracker' })
```

All ga events on the page are then sent with...

```
ga('MyTracker.send', /* ... */)
```

### That works, but...

The vimeo script doesn't include the `MyTracker` prefix for events. As Far as I can tell, there's no way to make it use a named tracker (I could be wrong?). So, events look like...

```
ga("send", "event", "Video", "load", "My Super Awesome Video")
```

which gives this error (from GA debug):

> Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined

## Question

Is there a way to either...

1. Make the Vimeo analytics script use the named tracker? OR
2. Re-route these GA events from the default tracker to the named tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to either...

> Make the Vimeo analytics script use the named tracker? OR

**If you can't change the Vimeo analytics code then no**: it will be harcoded with `ga('send'` thus pointing to the main tracker.

> Re-route these GA events from the default tracker to the named
>   tracker?

**Yes using custom tasks**. For instance using [sendHitTask](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks), something along those lines:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga(function(tracker) {

  // Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
  var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');

  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
    // Send data to other tracker
    ga('MyTracker.send', /* ... */)

    // Comment below line if you don't want to send
    // data to original tracker
    originalSendHitTask(model);

  });
});
```

Comment: This worked. For my case, I didn't need to send to the original tracker, so I just called `tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) { ga('MyTracker.send', model.get('hitType'), model.get('eventCategory'), model.get('eventAction'), model.get('eventLabel')); })` directly after the `ga('create')`